# body.getTransform().setRotation(value) not working in box2d

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

Hi i want to set rotation of body without changing its position.
I came across a function of body.

```
 body.getTransform().setRotation();
```

But this function doesn't seems to work.

Am i doing something wrong . I know i can do it with

```
body.setTransform(x, y, angle);
```

but then i have to pass its position also and i don't want to do that.

Is there any other way I can only change the body angle.

Comment: Define "doesn't seems to work"

Comment: @Quirliom: obviously rotation does not change

Comment: But how is this verified? Is there a sprite which isn't updating? Is the value from getRotation() wrong?

Comment: unfortunately as of today there is no other way to do it, you must send its position aswell. iforce2d answer is the right one

Answer (score 1):

You can just give the existing position and angle to setTransform, if you don't want them to change. For example, this will have no effect:

```
body->SetTransform( body->GetTransform(), body->GetAngle() );
```

Comment: Paras already mentioned that he knows this method but dont want to use it. Though i also used the same method(as suggested by iforce2d) to rotate a body till now but dont you think that there shuld be a method which takes the angle as only parameter to rotate a body?? On the other hand i tried    body.getTransform().setRotation(); and  body.getTransform().setPosition(); method but none seems to work. why is it not working??? would be glad if someone clear the things here..